# How do I notify the container object that a property has changed from the object being changed?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged

**Background**: Essentially, I am making a Grid system in Xamarin.Forms with custom Android renderers since the built in Grid implementation is too slow for what we are trying to do (it can't handle 100,000 cells being scrolled simultaneously, which we need). I succeeded in doing this already with excess coupling, and now that I am refactoring to the way my supervisor asked, I have run into a problem.

**Scenario**:

```
//In Xamarin.Forms project
class GridItems : BindableObject { 
    //Handles/contains all logic to how this grid will be laid out and its children
}

//In Xamarin.Forms project
class Grid : View { 
    GridItems Source { get; set; }
}

//In Xamarin.Android project
class GridRenderer { 
    OnElementPropertyChanged() {
        //Here I can check what properties inside Grid changed
    }
}
```

This is obviously very simplified, but the reason it is setup this way is so that you can simply subclass GridItems to modify what type of items the grid takes in, what the string value of a cell/column should be, etc. and reuse the Grid and GridRenderer classes.

**Problem**:

When GridItems is modified within itself, I need Grid.GridItems to be notified. GridItems can raise it's property changed event, however that only fires off for local properties. I essentially need GridItems to be able to tell Grid "I have changed, raise YOUR GridItems property changed event", so that the GridRenderer can see the GridItems has changed (since Grid changed) and Invalidate itself, redrawing on the screen.

Is there a good way to notify the containing object that the property has changed from the property itself? Or am I approaching this problem all wrong?

Comment: This might be a bit naive, but have you looked at the [data binding guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/)? You can create a model that will be able to raise `PropertyChanged` which sounds like what you're going for, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to find a working way to do this, but it might not work for most future people since it is pretty specific to my scenario.

Essentially, Grid and GridItems both share a ViewModel (the pages ViewModel). This meant that when the binding for GridItems being modified, the ViewModel can simply notify Grid via bindings, so it's more like ViewModel is in charge.

I made a bindable boolean value in Grid called "Invalidate". Whenever ViewModel was modifying the children binding for GridItems, it would modify the Invalidate binding by setting it to true.

Now on the custom renderer, whenever it's ElementPropertyChange fired off for Grid, it would check if Invalidate fired & Invalidate is now set to true. In this case, it simply resets Invalidate to false in the element and then calls Invalidate on itself (forcing the Draw event to refire when possible and reload the screen).